# The property 'color' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter

How to fix this error. Message error: The property 'color' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
[image]

My code

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    // defaults for styles
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    selectedDateStyleColor = Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1.color!; //ERROR
    selectedSingleDateDecorationColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.seconday;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`selectedDateStyleColor = Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1.color!;`

with

`selectedDateStyleColor = Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1!.color;`

or

`selectedDateStyleColor = Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1?.color ?? Colors.black;`

It's the bodyText1 that can be null. In the latter case, you'll have to provide a default value as well for when that happens (like I did with Colors.black).

EDIT: when using the bang operator, the code will crash when the bodyText1 is null. Not that I've seen that happen with Theme-related variables until now, but I prefer using `?` over `!` whenever I haven't checked explicitly that the variable isn't null.

[Here's](https://tomek-polanski.medium.com/bang-operator-and-how-to-improve-your-dart-nullability-ddc49ffbc7ff) a good read on that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
  if(Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1 != null){
  if(Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1!.color != null){
    Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1!.color!;
  }
}
```

but also:

```
Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1?.color?;
```

REMEMBER :
Sound null safety makes types in code non-nullable by default and enables special static checks and compiler optimizations to guarantee that null-dereference errors won’t appear at runtime because they will be spotted at compile-time and fixed. Soundness means that you can trust the type system when it determines that something isn’t null because it can never make a mistake. You can achieve soundness only if all libraries you use in the project have null-safe code.